# Preventing XSS attacks in a Spring MVC application controller

Tags: java, security, spring, groovy, spring-mvc

One of the URL in my application is vulnerable to XSS attack, so I am handling it in the below way.

I created a util class:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HtmlUtils {
    public final static String tagStart = "\\<\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*\\=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\"\\>\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)\\>";

    public final static String tagEnd = "\\</\\w+\\>";

    public final static String tagSelfClosing = "\\<\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*\\=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\"\\>\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/\\>";

    public final static String htmlEntity = "&[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+;";

    public final static Pattern htmlPattern = Pattern.compile("(" + tagStart + ".*" + tagEnd + ")|(" + tagSelfClosing
            + ")|(" + htmlEntity + ")", Pattern.DOTALL);

    public static boolean isHtml(String s) {
        boolean ret = false;
        if (s != null) {
            ret = htmlPattern.matcher(s).find();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And in the controller, I am throwing an exception if the requested value has an HTML script:

```
def isValidRequest(request){
    def htmlRequest = false
    def params = request.getParameterNames(); 

    while(params.hasMoreElements()){
      String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
      def value = request.getParameter(paramName);
       htmlRequest = HtmlUtils.isHtml(value);
         if(BooleanUtils.isTrue(htmlRequest))
          break;        
      }

  if(BooleanUtils.isTrue(htmlRequest))
      throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
}
```

Does this look good or is there a better way to handle the XSS attack in the controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Don't use RegEx to prevent XSS attacks!

Why?

1. [**Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3626537)
2. [**There are much better ways to prevent XSS attacks.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5769859/3626537)

An example, using your code, modified to use [Spring HtmlUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape%28java.lang.String%29).

Please note that I changed names `s` to `input` and `ret` to `isHtml`, as these names indicate what the variable is intended for, rather than just what kind it is.

```
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;

public class HtmlUtils {
    /**
     * Verify if a string contains any HTML characters by comparing its
     * HTML-escaped version with the original.
     * @param String input  the input String
     * @return boolean  True if the String contains HTML characters
     */
    public static boolean isHtml(String input) {
        boolean isHtml = false;
        if (input != null) {
            if (!input.equals(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(input))) {
                isHtml = true;
            }
        }
        return isHtml;
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are other things to say about your code, but this is **very important**.

There is *much more* to truly preventing XSS attacks, depending on how critical your use case is. This page has a tremendous amount of useful information you may want to consider: [**XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F)

Answer (score 4):

You can use OWASP's ESAPI jar

```
json = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(json);
json = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(json);
```

Dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```